# Running .NET 4.0 app with reference to 2.0 library on machine with only 4.0 framework

Tags: c#, .net, clr, version

This would be a real pain to try to duplicate, so I'm hoping someone has a quick answer...

Suppose I have a .NET 4.0 application, with a reference to a .NET 2.0 library (SharpZipLib in this case). This of course works fine on a normal machine with .NET 2.0 and 4.0 installed.

If the server running this application has only .NET 4.0 and not 2.0 (or 3.0/3.5 etc.), what do I need to do to allow the .NET 2.0 library to run properly?

From what I've read, it looks like I may be able to put in a config setting for `supportedRuntime`, but I'm not quite understanding what exactly that does.

Will a config setting work, or would only .NET 4.0 libraries function in this environment?

(This is a hypothetical environment - I don't plan on ever having my own servers with 4.0 and not 2.0, but if someone is crazy enough to do it, I want to be able to support them).

Thanks

Comment: Nothing special is needed for a regular 2.0 assembly like SharpZipLib.  It loads without problem or config in a EXE that targets 4.0

Comment: Hans is correct - having a 4.0 app can load a 2.0 targetted library.  See my answer below - you shouldn't need to install the 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 fx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CLR can load older assemblies in the .net 4.0 framework.

Here's a good read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx

EDIT: updated quote from article.  Particularly notice the bold

> The .NET Framework 4 runtime—and all future runtimes—will be able to
>   run in-process with one another. While we did not back-port this
>   functionality to older runtimes (1.0 through 3.5), we did make sure
>   that 4 and beyond will be able to run in-process with any single older
>   runtime. **In other words, you will be able to load 4, 5 and 2.0 in
>   the same process, but you will not be able to load 1.1 and 2.0 in the
>   same process.** .NET Frameworks 2.0 through 3.5 all run on the 2.0
>   runtime and so have no conflicts with one another, as shown in Figure
>   2.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good article. It doesn't mention the `<supportedRuntimes>` setting, but it does provide a lot of insight.

Comment: Note that for In-Proc SxS to be done, both runtimes have to be installed.

Comment: @JoeEnos: I think the `supportedRuntimes` bit only applies to the main application.  See Daniel's answer -- the runtime used for dependencies is determined by the main application.

Comment: @Daniel - Right - and in .net 4.0, you don't need to do that, it will load 2.0 directly without having 2.0 installed.  That's what is cool about it.

Comment: @Daniel - not with .net 4.0 both Fx don't need to be installed.  updated quote

Comment: Where is it stated that the 4.0 runtime includes the 2.0 runtime? What is different is that in 4.0 (and later) you can have multiple runtimes active in the same process.

Comment: This is only true for executables that load the CLR themselves.  Like a COM server or a C++/CLI assembly that loads the CLR through an exported native DLL entrypoint.  A regular 2.0 .NET assembly that gets loaded by an EXE that targets 4.0 doesn't require nor load the version 2.0 CLR.

Answer (score 6):

From http://neilblackburn.blogspot.com/2009/10/net-framework-40-backward-compatibility.html (and, transitively, http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/08/03/installing-net-framework-v4-0-and-running-net-2-0-3-0-3-5-3-5sp1-applications.aspx):

> Now, I knew that you can’t just take a 3.5 Service Pack 1 application
>   and run it on the V4.0 CLR. It needs a V2.0 CLR or reconfiguring with
>   a `<supportedRuntimes/>` tag in order to bend the application to run on
>   the V4.0 CLR and that bending might be something that you don’t want
>   to do.

Comment: This is for migrating applications to the new runtime, not libraries.

Answer (score 2):

From the link in bryanmac's answer ([In-Process Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx)):

> This means that if an application is recompiled to run against the .NET Framework 4 runtime and still has dependent assemblies built against .NET 2.0, those dependents will load on the .NET 4 runtime as well.

That can mean, however, that there may be bugs due to being run on a different runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source to SharpZipLib you could just rebuild it as .NET 4.0

Comment: Thanks - probably wouldn't be a big deal in this specific case to do that, but I don't want that to be the default answer for other libraries I may use in the future.